# PHP __toArray() or __toObject() override?

Tags: php, class, tostring, overriding

Is there an equivalent to get a reorganized standardized object from a normal class? Something that works along the same lines as PHP's __toString() override method.

Okay, so I have this method that grabs a bunch of stations, and returns an object model, which handles a bunch of other methods to get other related data. So in this instance when I call the object that contains the locations "$locations" I want to get back either a flat associative array of object properties, or an array of objects that I can easily encode to JSON. If I get an array of location objects back, I just want $location to be directly converted to a JSON string. Just like if I were to refer to $location as a location object that contained __toString() and it would automatically produce a string representation. In this case I want an standard object or array, and not a string. Is there a way to do this?

Code sample below:

```
public function stnSearch() {
    $locations = DBO::getInstance()->query("
        SELECT " . DBO_Location::COLUMNS . "
        FROM " . DBO_Location::TABLE_NAME . " AS a
        WHERE a.title LIKE '%" . $_REQUEST['query'] . "%'
    ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, DBO_Location::MODEL);

    Util::debug($locations); // want this to produce a standard object for each model without having to do an additional loop

    exit();
}
```

Comment: Show examples of wanted behaviour.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get a `stdClass` object from custom class with, for example all properties of that custom class instance set?

Comment: Well __toString will help you convert anything within a class to a string return. I have selective properties within a class that I want to be returned as a standard object, because I need the JSON for an AJAX call, and I cannot directly access the PHP methods that return this information from Javascript.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh If you are trying to make a JSON output from selected class properties, why not just specify a custom `__toString()` method that builds a `stdClass` object with the properties you are interested in and then returns a JSON-encoding of it? Or simply implement your own `toJSON()` method.

Comment: @MikeBrant That's a good idea. I want to avoid using __toString, because that's already doing something else, but I guess just creating  the toJson object would be workable.

Comment: Implement [ArrayAccess](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) and you can use your class as if it was an array without calling any conversion methods.

Comment: That's not going to do it. It's still dumping out an array of location objects. I need to flatten the object down to either an array or standard object.

Answer (score 14):

In php 5.4 and above, if your class impliments `JsonSerializable`, you can add a `jsonSerialize` method that will be called by `json_encode`:

```
<?php
class MyClass implements JsonSerializable
{
    public $foo;

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return array(
            "foo"=>$this->foo,
            "name"=>"MyClass"
        );
    }
}

$x = new MyClass();
$x->foo = "hello";
echo json_encode($x);
```

Will print:

```
{"foo":"hello","name":"MyClass"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the feedback everyone! I ended up having to create a standard method in each class (one for toArray(), and one for toJSON()). This is not the desired solution, but it will have to do.

The toArray() method flattens out the complex class so that the array has properties available to either toObject() or toJSON() to digest. For instance I had a few methods that format data for output to HTML, and those do not automatically set to a local property in the class, so I need to set that up manually. via the method I mentioned above.

toArray() example:

```
public static function toArray($logs) {
    $b = new ArrayObject();

    $b->offsetSet('id', $logs->getId());
    $b->offsetSet('frequency', $logs->getFrequency());
    $b->offsetSet('formatted_frequency', number_format($logs->getFrequency(), 2, '.', ''));
    $b->offsetSet('mode', $logs->getMode());
    $b->offsetSet('time_on', $logs->getTimeOn()->format(self::JSON_DATE_FORMAT));
    $b->offsetSet('description', $logs->getDescription());
    $b->offsetSet('receive_location', $logs->receiveCoordinates()->toArray());

    ...

    return $b->getArrayCopy();
}
```

to get JSON object:

```
public static function toJSON($logs) {
    $b = self::toArray($logs);

    return json_encode($b);
}
```

Again this was not the desired result, but it gets the job done. Ideally I would love to have had a way to establish a method in the parent class that could be overridden, if there were extraneous properties that needed handling in a child class.